# Write a regular expression to match these ?, ~, ^, | and *

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone help me with creating a regular expression to except these five symbols: `?~^|*` all other symbols should be accepted.

My scenario: I have one text box. I am entering some text into that text box, if the text contains these `?~^|*` symbols, it should throw a validation error.

Comment: `^[^?~\^|*]+$.test(your_input_string)`

Comment: use this tool https://regexr.com/

Comment: If you personally are unable to write an expression then use available online generators, here is example one: https://txt2re.com Stackoverflow is not kind of forum where you will get ready to use code without your own input in form of code written by you already.

Comment: ^[^?~\^|*]+$ this is working only with symbols. If I Enter text with symbols it's not working. 
Example: textwithsymbols~ this accepting but in my case it should not accept

Answer (score 1):

Use `test` with RegEx pattern.Put what ever you want to check inside `[]`. `focusout` for when user leave that text box to check user input.

```js
$("#target").focusout(function() {
  var testString = $('#target').val();
  if (/[?~^|*]/.test(testString))
    console.log('Invalid character in input');
  else
    console.log('test pass')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='target' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if(yourstring.match(/[\?|\^|~|\||\*]/) != null) {/*Check input*/}`.
You have a lot of special characters you want to match, so you need to escape them all with backslashes. The problem you were having with only accepting symbols is because you put `^` and `$` around your regex, which mark the start and end of string. To match anywhere in the string, just leave theese characters out.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what language are you using, but something like

```
[^?~^|*]+$
```

should work for you, as "[ ]" defines a character class, which will match any of the listed characters. And putting "^" in front - negates the match.

You can read more about negated classes [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) ;)